# Upload Assets Manually

Tags: assets

Is it possible to upload assets into the folders listed in the asset section on the server manually/directly? And then "sync up" the system so the ui sees these?

Used to be able to do this in expression engine via a sync button and i don't see how to do that here, but perhaps im missing the trick?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, after uploading via FTP, you will need to tell Craft to go and index the new assets: **Settings** > **Tools** > **Update Asset Indexes**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just upload them through the filemanager?

Comment: I just noticed you can drag them all in in batch which is nice. That should work. But I also have a case of a large file that wont seem to upload it just hangs...

Comment: you can set the upload limit in your general config file. If your image keeps hanging it's most likely that you have to adjust your upload limit there.